# How can I make my for loop in PHP display every number individually?

Tags: php, for-loop

This is my for loop:

```
for($num1 = 0; $num1 < count($new_array); $num1++);
```

If I echo $num1, it will display 124 since I have 124 of $new_array, my question is, is there a way to display the number like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and so on, instead of one big number?

I want to be able to use $num1 as an auto incremental ID for my divs, example:

```
<div class='toggleDiv$num1'></div>
```

That way I will have a new div with a unique ID for every $new_array.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Edit: more clarification.

When I echo $num1, I would like it to look like this:
1
2
3
4
5
6
...

Instead of:

124

Comment: Could you please provide the [mcve]? Where have you placed the `echo` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php for($num1 = 0; $num1 < count($new_array); $num1++) { echo $num1; }
```

For your div scenario:

```
<?php 
for($num1 = 0; $num1 < count($new_array); $num1++) { 
    echo '<div class="myDiv' . $num1 . '">'; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you a ton, wasn't much of difficulty after all, but I appreciate it alot.

Comment: are you free to answer another question? If so, here it is:

As I wrote, I would use $num1 as ID for my divs, if I do class="myDiv$num1", the ID will be all 124 characters, how would I limit that to only use 1 for every new div?

Comment: You have to write the div inside the loop. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<br />` tag after `echo`

Example:

```
echo $num1 . "<br />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three options, they do the same, they just use different PHP syntax

Option A

```
<?php for($num1 = 0; $num1 < count($new_array); $num1++){ ?>
   <div class='toggleDiv<?php echo $num1; ?>'></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Option B, I find this a bit more readable (*notice it doesn't use braces but a colon*)

```
<?php for($num1 = 0; $num1 < count($new_array); $num1++): ?>
   <div class='toggleDiv<?php echo $num1; ?>'></div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Option C

```
<?php
for($num1 = 0; $num1 < count($new_array); $num1++) {
   echo "<div class='toggleDiv{$num1}'></div>"
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID and class are not the same actually...

```
<?php
for($num1 = 0; $num1 < count($new_array); $num1++) {
echo '<div id="myDivIdIs' . $num1 . '" class="myDiv">$num1</div>';
} 
?>
```

unless you want to create and deal with $i+++ css classes